# Problems when buying tokens from a contract using BNB

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am creating this smart contract, it creates and adds all tokens to my wallet.
Then I send all the tokens in my wallet to my contract.

However, when from another wallet I send BNB for the contract I wanted him to return a number of tokens that are with my contract.

When I do this the transfer fails and sends the following error message:

**Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [out of gas]**

Queria saber se estou fazendo algo errado, ou como devo fazer para que meu contrato tenha **gas**.

Transaction Details: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x7ef36e49e3c6f77716aee79cefbde6c298c3ddeef16ed12dbe613573661135bb

Smart Contract:

> ```
> pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
>
> interface IERC20 {
>
> function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
> function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
> function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
>
> function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
> function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
> function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
>
>
> event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
> event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value); }
>
>
> contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {
>
> string public constant name = "ByeSeel";
> string public constant symbol = "BYS";
> uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
>
>
> event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
> event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
>
>
> mapping(address => uint256) balances;
>
> mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
>
> uint256 totalSupply_ = 100 * 10 ** 18;
>
> using SafeMath for uint256;
>
> constructor() public {
> balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
> }
>
> function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
> return totalSupply_;
> }
>
> function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
>     return balances[tokenOwner];
> }
>
> function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
>     require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
>     balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
>     balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
>     emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
>     return true;
> }
>
> function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
>     allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
>     emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
>     return true;
> }
>
> function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
>     return allowed[owner][delegate];
> }
>
> function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
>     require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
>     require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);
>
>     balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
>     allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
>     balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
>     emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
>     return true;
> }
>
> event Received(address, uint);
>  receive() external payable {
>  emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
> }
>
>  }
>
> library SafeMath {
> function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
>   assert(b <= a);
>   return a - b;
> }
>
> function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
>   uint256 c = a + b;
>   assert(c >= a);
>   return c;
> } }
>
> contract DEX {
>
> event Bought(uint256 amount);
> event Sold(uint256 amount);
>
>
> IERC20 public token;
>
> constructor() public {
>     token = new ERC20Basic();
> }
>
> function buy() payable public {
>     uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
>     uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
>     require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some Ether");
>     require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
>     token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);
>     emit Bought(amountTobuy);
> }
>
> function sell(uint256 amount) public {
>     require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
>     uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
>     require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
>     token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
>     msg.sender.transfer(amount);
>     emit Sold(amount);
> }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the transaction detail on BscScan, you're trying to send 0.1 BNB and not calling any function.

Your contract does not have the [receive()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#receive-ether-function), nor the [fallback()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#fallback-function) function, that would accept the incoming BNB.

So all you need to do is implement the `receive()` function. Mind the `payable` modifier that allows this function to accept BNB.

```
contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {
    // rest of your code

    receive() external payable {
        // can call the buy() function
        buy();
    }
}
```

You can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr3HO.jpg) that when you send 100 wei (or 100 jager in case of BNB) to the contract, the `receive()` function executes the `buy()` function and produces the `Bought` event log.

Here's the whole code implemented on your contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {

function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    
}


contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {

string public constant name = "ByeSeel";
string public constant symbol = "BYS";
uint8 public constant decimals = 18;


//event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
//event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);


mapping(address => uint256) balances;

mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

uint256 totalSupply_ = 100 * 10 ** 18;

using SafeMath for uint256;

constructor() public {
balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
}

function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
return totalSupply_;
}

function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[tokenOwner];
}

function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
    require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
    return true;
}

function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
    return allowed[owner][delegate];
}

function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
    require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
    require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

    balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
    allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
    return true;
}

event Received(address, uint);
 receive() external payable {
 emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

 }

library SafeMath {
function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  assert(b <= a);
  return a - b;
}

function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
  uint256 c = a + b;
  assert(c >= a);
  return c;
} }

contract DEX {

    event Bought(uint256 amount);
    event Sold(uint256 amount);
    
    
    IERC20 public token;
    
    constructor() public {
        token = new ERC20Basic();
    }
    
    function buy() payable public {
        uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
        uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some Ether");
        require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
        token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);
        emit Bought(amountTobuy);
    }
    
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
        uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
        emit Sold(amount);
    }
    
    receive() external payable {
        buy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Find the code you spoke about, I modified the question with the update. I was able to successfully send BNB to the contract, but he did not return my token to me, do I need to implement fallback ()? Could you give me an example?

Comment: The snippet in my answer reacts to your original question about the error when you're sending BNB to a contract. It allows you to send BNB to the contract, so you (or any user) can later call the `sell()` function and the contract has now BNB to send back to the user. It doesn't return any tokens... If you want to buy tokens, you need to call the `buy()` function directly or from within the `receive()` function.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo I updated my answer with example of calling the `buy()` function from within the `receive()` ... Can you specify what do you mean by "doesn't work"? I was able to successfully send ETH (should be same for BNB) in Remix and didn't run into any issue: 1) Commented out the redefinition of `Approval` and `Transfer` events in your `ERC20Basic` (they are already defined in the `IERC20`) and deployed `DEX`. 2) The deployment of DEX gave `100 * 10 ** 18` tokens to my deployer address. 3) Then I sent 100 wei to the contract from the same (deployer) address and received 100 tokens.

Comment: Incredible as it seems mine can't call the buy that way, could you send me the whole code so I can see how you are doing?

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo I updated the answer with the code. Compiled with Solidity 0.8.1

Comment: I was putting buy () on receive () from within ERC20Basic.
This must have been the error.

Comment: That makes sense. The user is interacting with the `DEX` contract - not with the `ERC20Basic` when they are sending a transaction. So the `DEX` contract needs to implement the `recieve()` function. Glad it works now.

Comment: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x86ceb61baf69729db13a2e7208d48bbc1dca8d01


Now it is receiving but it is not returning the tokens.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo Please verify the contract on BscScan. There's probably something done differently and it's very hard to debug without seeing the source code.

Comment: The contract I'm selecting to compile in Remix is ​​ERC20Basic, but in this case the Buy () function is in the DEX contract, isn't that why it's not working? I believe that I am not doing the compilation the right way.

https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xa18fb95f7501a447dfe97c91eeb2eb5692fc9e22#code

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo You need to compile the DEX contract - not the ERC20Basic. See my second comment here.

Comment: But if I don't compile the ERC20Basic how will I generate the tokens?

Comment: The ERC20Basic gets compiled as well, because it's used by the `token` property in DEX. But the main contract needs to be the `DEX`.

Comment: https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0xb570E6Fff85CBE695c9394bDa7d55fb38a009A28
When compiled by DEX the contract is not generated automatically, I cannot even see the name, symbol or total of currencies.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo That's a separate issue. Please open a new question so that we don't spam the comments, show what you've tried so far, produce a reproducible example, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439700/token-information-does-not-show-when-compiled