# Token information does not show when compiled

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am using the code below to create a smart contract, which receives BNB and sends the token created by the contract back.

I'm using Remix, and selecting the DEX contract to compile.

However, when I do this, the Token information does not appear on BscScan.

Example: https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0xb570E6Fff85CBE695c9394bDa7d55fb38a009A28

And I can't add it to my wallet either, it says that the token code doesn't recognize it.

> ```
> // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
> pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
>
> interface IERC20 {
>
>     function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
>     function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
>     function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
>
>     function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
>     function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
>     function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
>
>
>     event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
>     event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
>
> }
>
>
> contract ERC20Basic is IERC20{
>
>     string public constant name = "ByeSeel";
>     string public constant symbol = "BYS";
>     uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
>
>
> //event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
> //event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
>
>
> mapping(address => uint256) balances;
>
> mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
>
> uint256 totalSupply_ = 10000000 * 10 ** 18;
>
> using SafeMath for uint256;
>
> constructor() {
>     balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
> }
>
> function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
>     return totalSupply_;
> }
>
> function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
>     return balances[tokenOwner];
> }
>
> function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
>     require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
>     balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
>     balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
>     emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
>     return true;
> }
>
> function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
>     allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
>     emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
>     return true;
> }
>
> function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
> return allowed[owner][delegate];
> }
>
> function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
> require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
> require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);
>
> balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
> allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
> balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
> emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
> return true;
> }
>
> event Received(address, uint);
>  receive() external payable {
>  emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
> }
>
> }
>
> library SafeMath {
> function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
>   assert(b <= a);
>   return a - b;
> }
>
> function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
>    uint256 c = a + b;
>    assert(c >= a);
>    return c;
> } }
>
> contract DEX {
>
>     event Bought(uint256 amount);
>     event Sold(uint256 amount);
>
>
>     IERC20 public token;
>
>     constructor() {
>         token = new ERC20Basic();
>     }
>
>     function buy() payable public {
>         uint256 amountTobuy = msg.value;
>         uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
>         require(amountTobuy > 0, "You need to send some Ether");
>         require(amountTobuy <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
>         token.transfer(msg.sender, amountTobuy);
>         emit Bought(amountTobuy);
>     }
>
>     function sell(uint256 amount) public {
>         require(amount > 0, "You need to sell at least some tokens");
>         uint256 allowance = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
>         require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");
>         token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
>         payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
>         emit Sold(amount);
>     }
>
>     receive() external payable {
>     buy();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the DEX contract was not extending to the ERC20Basic contract
So I had to do:
contract DEX is ERC20Basic
This solved it, but I still have problems with the purchase and sale contract.